# AutoHotkey ControlFocus fails for Edit Control

Tags: autohotkey

I have a window, created by AutoHotkey, with one button and one edit control on it.
What I am trying to do is to bring back the input focus to the Edit control after I click the button. By means of WinSpy (many thanks to Robert Kuster), I have the following information about the Edit control.

```
Handle : 0x00330786 (changes every time I start the application)
Control ID : 4
Class : Edit
Window Title : some window title
Parent Window Class : AutoHotkeyGUI
```

Below is the statement I am using in my script.

```
ControlFocus, MyEdit, some window title
```

BTW, AutoHotkey help suggests to leave the control name and replace the window title with HWND of the target control as an alternative. Please guide on how to accomplish this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have your own GUI built with AHK. Why don't you use `GuiControl, Focus`?

Comment: MCL has a point.  The `GuiControl` is autohotkey's way of working with it's own controls.  You would only use `ControlFocus` if you are working with controls for external windows.  MCL - maybe you should present that as an answer.

Comment: Thank your for the points. BTW, is this forum (stackoverflow) is like Microsoft Forum in which the user asking question should select an answer as the best one? If so where is that function?

Comment: yes pretty much so... :P but stackoverflow is better ;)

Comment: You can accept answers. The little *chat* we're having are just your question's comments. If a comment is a perfect solution to your problem, ask the commenter to post it as an answer. If a comment led you to a solution, post your solution as an answer and accept it (and if you're polite, mention the commenter).

Comment: It seems we all are polite ;) MCL and BGM has the best answers. Unfortunately, my reputation is NOT enough to vote you up.

Comment: Agreed. No need to upvote. Upvoting comments doesn't give me reputation anyway, AND THAT'S ALL I WANT! All jokes aside, if you got your script working, I suggest doing the following two things: 1) Provide a sample of your script in the question (what you've tried and didn't work, maybe including some portions of the GUI buildung code) 2) Post an answer (in the input field below), showing the changes you made to get it to work. After some time, you will be able to accept it and thus showing people you don't need help anymore.

Comment: alright ~ for the help I am receiving, how can I help promoting reputation of the contributors to my question if upvoting your comments is not gonna give you any reputation? Do you mean posting answer to my question after your helpful comments is what gives you reputations? Is that how stackoverflow is working in relation to gaining reputations?

Comment: Haha sorry, it was just a joke. I don't think any commenter here cares about rep. People mainly gain rep by getting upvotes to their questions or answers, or if their answer was accepted. It's totally fine if you just post your solution as an answer. Giving other people that may have the same problem a solution is much more important than any kind of "points".

Comment: :D I am sorry; all that is because the stackoverflow's motivation model is kinda confusing for me. Happy chat.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a piece of Autohotkey script using

```
GuiControl, Focus, ControlName
```

in order to change the input focus to the Edit control (namely Completion) after button "Show My Progress" is clicked.

```
%WinTitle% = some window title
Gui, Add, Text, vLabel cWhite, Reading Completion
Gui, Add, Edit, vCompletion ym w40  ; The ym option starts a new column of controls.
Gui, Add, Progress, vMyProgress w300 h30 xp+50  yp-5
Gui, Add, Button, xp yp+50, Show My Progress
GuiControl,, Completion, %iniCompletion%
Gui, Show, h140, %WinTitle%
ControlClick, Show My Progress, %WinTitle%
**GuiControl, Focus, Completion**
return

ButtonShowMyProgress:
Gui, Submit, NoHide  ; Save the input from the user to each control's associated variable.
MyCompletionPercentage:=(Completion / (PageEnd-PageStart+1)) * 100
PercentageRounded:=Round(MyCompletionPercentage,0)
GuiControl,, MyProgress, %PercentageRounded%
**GuiControl, Focus, Completion**
return
```

Many thanks to MCL and BGM for their comments ...

> If I understand correctly, you have your own GUI built with AHK. Why
>   don't you use GuiControl, Focus?  – MCL
>
> MCL has a point. The GuiControl is autohotkey's way of working with it's own controls. You would only use ControlFocus if you are working with controls for
>   external windows. MCL - maybe you should present that as an answer.  – BGM